# Async for Long operation with HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asynchronous, iis, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I am figuring out performance of my C# web api. I wrote a very simple `HelloWorld` response:

```
public class HelloWorldController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {

        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("HelloWorld")
        };
    }
}
```

I tested by using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) I set 1000 Users request and it worked perfectly (CPU usage up to 100%). But the problem is that when the operation of the api take bit longer, the response become worse, got only 3 responses each (CPU usage <7%). It took minuets for 1000 users request.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent("HelloWorld")
        };
    }
```

After google I come up with idea of using async but still I got same problem. I don't know what the problem is or my code implementation. Below is my sample implementation.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage()
        {
            Content = new StringContent(await LongOperationAsync())
        };
    }
    private string LongOperation()
    {
        //long operation here
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return "HelloWorld";
    }

    private Task<string> LongOperationAsync()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => LongOperation());
    }
```

Anyone know what is the problem or any idea regarding to this problem?

Comment: What do you think that `Thread.Sleep(1000);` is actually doing here?

Answer (score 4):

`async` and `await` are not magic bullets that just "mak teh codez moah awesomz". [On ASP.NET, `await` enables your application to be more scalable (and respond to changes in scale more quickly) *by making optimum use of the thread pool*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx).

So, if you're freeing up a thread pool thread (`await`) but using up another thread pool thread (`StartNew`), you're not going to gain anything. In particular, [exposing a fake-async method for a synchronous API is an antipattern](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/).

If possible, the best solution is to make `LongOperationAsync` a naturally-asynchronous operation:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
  return new HttpResponseMessage()
  {
    Content = new StringContent(await LongOperationAsync())
  };
}

private async Task<string> LongOperationAsync()
{
  //long operation here
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  return "HelloWorld";
}
```

If this isn't possible, then you may as well keep it synchronous. Using `Task.Run` (or [even worse](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), `StartNew`) isn't going to help at all.

Answer (score 3):

The Method LongOperationAsync And LongOperation also should be **async** :

```
private async Task<string> LongOperation()
{
    //long operation here
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return "HelloWorld";
}
private async Task<string> LongOperationAsync()
{
    var rt =  await Task.Run(() => LongOperation());
    return rt;
}
```

see:
[Asynchronous programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async)